# iPhone and floating point math

Tags: iphone, floating-point

I have following code:

```
    float totalSpent;
    int intBudget;
    float moneyLeft;

totalSpent += Amount;
moneyLeft =  intBudget - totalSpent;
```

And this is how it looks in debugger: http://www.braginski.com/math.tiff

Why would moneyLeft calculated by the code above is .02 different compared to the expression calculated by the debugger?

Expression windows is correct, yet code above produces wrong by .02 result. It only happens for a very large numbers (yet way below int limit)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

A single-precision `float` has 23 bits of precision. That means that every calculation is rounded to 23 binary digits. This means that if you have a computation that, say, adds a very small number to a very large number, rounding may result in strange results.

Imagine that you are doing math in scientific notation decimal by hand, under the rule that you may only have four significant figures. Let's say I ask you to write twelve in scientific notation, with four significant figures. Remembering junior high school, you write:

1.200 × 10<sup>1</sup>

Now I say compute the square of 12, and then add 0.5. That is easy enough:

1.440×10<sup>2</sup> + 0.005×10<sup>2</sup> = 1.445×10<sup>2</sup>

How about twelve cubed plus 0.75:

1.728×10<sup>3</sup> + 0.00075×10<sup>3</sup> = 1.72875×10<sup>3</sup>

But remember, I only gave you room for **four significant digits**, so you must **round**; then we get:

1.728×10<sup>3</sup> + 7.5×10<sup>-1</sup> = 1.729×10<sup>3</sup>

See? The lack of precision can make the computation come out with unexpected results.

In your example, you've got 999999 in a calculation where you're trying to be precise to 0.01. log<sub>2</sub>(999999) = 19.93 and log<sub>2</sub>(0.01) = -6.64. The difference is more than 23; therefore you would need more than 23 binary digits to perform this calculation accurately.

Because floating point mathematics rounds-off precision by its very nature, it is usually a bad choice for currency computation, where you must be accurate to the last cent. But are you really concerned with fractions of a cent in your application? If not, then why not do away with the decimal point altogether, and simply store cents (instead of dollars) in a 64-bit integer? 2<sup>64</sup>¢ is more than the GDP of the entire planet.

Comment: Excellent explanations, thanks! I just re-wrote the entire app (thankfully all many calculation were in one class) to use NSDecimalNumber and it started to work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Floating point will always produce strange results with money type calculations.

The golden rule is that floating point is good for things you measure litres,yards,lightyears,bushels etc. etc. but not for things you count like
sheep, beans, buttons etc.

Most money calculations are to do with counting pennies so use integer math
and you wont get the strange results. Either use a fixed decimal arithimatic 
library (which would probably be overkill on an iPhone) or store your amounts
as whole numbers of cents and only convert to $ and cents on display.

Comment: Thank you, James. See comment above. Since I never programmed financial kinds of app, it never occurred to me that float is a wrong type